# How to lower the critical temperature of the CPU, so thermal throttling starts earlier

Tags: power-management, cpu, overheating, temperature

I have an old Laptop with a broken heat sink, which leads the CPU to heat up to 80°C during small workloads, and briefly reaches 100°C during higher workloads (e.g. during system updates and compiling code).
When running lm_sensors, i recently found out that the critical(as well as maximum) temperature of my CPU is set to 100°C, meaning thermal throttling is not really doing anything unless the temperature already reached the maximum allowed temperature.

Is there any way to lower the critical temperature so I can test if thermal throttling would keep temperatures lower while not slowing down anything too much? I know that this is a suboptimal solution at best, but I'd like to extend the lifespan of this laptop as long as possible.

Edit: The CPU is an Intel i7-6700HQ

Comment: What kind of CPU is in the notebook? If it’s an Intel Core-series, you may be able to do it …

Comment: I use [TLP](https://askubuntu.com/a/1309400/968501) on some old machines to manage CPU/GPU heating.

Comment: @matigo, the CPU is an Intel i7-6700HQ

Comment: It's already asked here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/171397/limit-cpu-usage-in-terms-of-temperature